# How to get context item menu position when right click in ToolStripMenuItem_Click function relative to Grid?

Tags: c#, grid, contextmenu, ultrawingrid, toolstripmenu

I have ultraWinGrid, I want to copy cell's value to clipboard. For that, I want to get the X position of context menu when user right clicks on the grid. I want to get this position in **ToolStripMenuItem_click** function.

For that, I am taking grid's column width

```
int column1Width = myGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].CellSizeResolved.Width;
```

it will return width of column1.
Then I want to get the cursor position with respect to Grid.
I tried to get the position of cursor using

```
Cursor.Position.X
```

This is returning position with respect to whole screen but I want position with **respect to grid** in which user has right clicked.

Once I get the position of cursor, I will loop through selected row, then check position of cursor and width of column and accordingly get the cell's value and copy that to clipboard.

Comment: https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/wingrid-determining-the-location-of-a-specific-cell

Comment: Thank you @dr.null, it solved my purpose completely.